# What does it mean SIZE in top command?

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, freebsd

I have a c++ app. its run on freebsd. I have a problem ı guess its about memory.

Normally my app work normaly 3-4 days. I sometimes  check top command in ssh. SIZE always increase 4mb. Its not regular increase (sometime increase 4mb after 5 min sometimes 30min etc)

My application is 32bit(yes its old project) if size reach 4gb my app core its crash and down.

ı would like to learn. Which processes include in SIZE value.
[Image from SSH top command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scx4g.png)

Comment: Sounds like there is (at least one) memory leak. Look at where you allocate memory and see whether it is ever deallocated. The size is probably the amount if virtual memory used by the process.

Comment: Your program is leaking memory. Eventually the amount of memory that's used by your program reaches the maximum allowed by your operating system, and it crashes.

Comment: top was a great start. You now know you have a problem. If you're using top, valgrind is probably available. Valgrind can be a hard tool to understand, but it is very good at locating leaks and other memory errors. Fortunately There are folks here at Stack Overflow that can help you interpret the output.

Comment: Res value always 1500-2000 max. What is different res and size  ?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/q/772629/94862, https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/top-1-size-vs-mem.19147/